# MySQL date interval with specific date format

Tags: mysql

I have date column field it's data look like 2014-05. how i get previous 6th month interval. My mysql query below

```
SELECT name,grade from users where data_year  BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT('2014-04', '%Y-%m') -  INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND DATE_FORMAT('2014-04', '%Y-%m')
```

I got result when i put with days like 2014-04-31

Comment: I pass a date format param when i make procedure call

Comment: Pass a strongly-typed date parameter instead with the actual date you want. You shouldn't have to use formatting unless you are creating a string to display to the user.

Comment: I have no that kind of data. I thought it possible to handle. what i do with that?

Comment: Where did you find the date then? Where did `2014-04` come from? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: This `2014-05` is **not a date**. This one `2014-05-01` is.

Comment: In my table column have 2014-04 this much only. This is string column. May i use STR_TO_DATE? If i add -01 with this string it possible right?

Comment: First, you should update the question with the relevant details. What you are asking isn't how to format a date. Format means convert a date to a string. You are asking how to *parse* a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings you used aren't valid dates as they don't contain the day. If you want to use a [date literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) in a SQL statement you should use the form `DATE '2014-04-01'`, eg

```
SELECT name,grade 
from users 
where date_column  BETWEEN  DATE '2014-04-01' - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
                      AND DATE '2014-04-01'
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments it seems the question actually is - how to parse an incomplete date string. You can use `STR_TO_DATE` for that, but you'll have to append `-01` at the end, otherwise you'll get an invalid date with `0` for the day of month, ie `20140-04-00` instead of `2014-04-01`.